# Blazor Allow Anonymous For Razor Page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a .net cor 3.1 Blazor server project. I use the default identity system in this project. I want to access a specific razor page without login. How do I do that? Any Idea?

I tried adding `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` to the razor page. But it did not work for me

_Host.cshtml

```
page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@namespace has.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@attribute [Authorize]
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>has</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/custom_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="_content/AntDesign/css/ant-design-blazor.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="_content/BlazorInputFile/inputfile.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/AntDesign/js/ant-design-blazor.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Blazor.ContextMenu/blazorContextMenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/863157cf0e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Error404 />
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>

    <AntContainer />
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Comment: I think I most recently did it (on net5) with an auth middleware that created a substitute identity principal for that one page.. just trying to find the code..

Comment: Can [this answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/248835/allow-anonymous-user-on-a-blazor-page.html) help you?

Comment: Which page you are trying to apply `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]`? I didn't see it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found an answer. I created another _Host.cshtml with `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` in a separate folder inside of the `Pages` folder and I put my razor page in that folder.

Add `@layout PublicLayout` to your anonymous access component. In my case, MyAnonymousComponent.razor. `PublicLayout` is `PublicSection/PublicLayout.razor`

My project structure is like this

```
MyProject
   -Pages
      -Section1
      -Section2
      -Shared
          _Layout.cshtml
      -PublicSection     // This folder has anonymous access components
          _Host.cshtml
          _Layout.cshtml
          MyAnonymousComponent.razor
          PublicApp.razor
          PublicLayout.razor
       _Host.cshtml

   -Shared      
      MainLayout.razor

   App.razor
   _Imports.razor
   Program.cs
   Startup.cs
```

#### PublicSection/_Host.cshtml

```cs
@page "/publicsection"
@using has.Pages.PublicRazor
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@namespace has.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <base href="~/PublicSection" />
    // rest is same as Original _Host.cshtml file
</head>
<body>
    <app>
        <component type="typeof(PublicApp)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </app>

    // rest is same as Original _Host.cshtml file
</body>
</html>
```

#### PublicApp.razor

```cs
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(PublicLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(PublicLayout)">
                <Error404 />
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
    <AntContainer />
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

#### PublicLayout.razor

```cs
@inherits LayoutComponentBase;

<Content Class="site-layout-background content-pan">
    @Body
</Content>

@code {
    
}
```

#### Startup.cs

```cs
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
       endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
       endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/PublicSection/{**segment}","/PublicRazor/_Host");
       endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    });
...
```

Comment: Hi, there is some missing information in your answer., its difficult to understand. What is PublicRazor ? Why are you creating a PublicApp.cshtml ?

Comment: I think this is a great answer but I think the files are misnamed: `PublicApp.cshtml` should be `PublicApp.razor` ? And your `PublicApp.razor` is in fact your `PublicLayout.razor` file. I'll edit the answe to fix this

Comment: Another note for anyone using this solution: the files need to be in the `/Pages` folder tree (as in the example) or the `MapFallbackToPage` won't work.

Comment: It works for me! My mistake before was using:

```endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/public","/_Public");```

instead of

```endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/public/{**segment}","/_Public");```

Comment: Would love this to work (well, I'd love it to work without this huge work around). However I get this error - InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /PublicRazor/_Host, area: } . Is this similar to what you saw before your fix @RafaelCaviquioli? Your suggestion isn't working for me unfortunately.

Comment: Please check out my UseEndpoints:

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub().RequireAuthorization();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/public/{**segment}","/_Public");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health"); });

Comment: Initially this solution worked for me. After a few months, I needed to create a page with more componets with logic, initially, I just had a static html page as public. The page is displayed properly, but it gets an error when it tries to make an HTTP request to /authorize the endpoint and crashing the application because of CORS. I don't expect to see any authorization initiation in this public page. i.stack.imgur.com/IhgzC.png