# Blazor server Allow Anonymous page when @attribute [Authorized] set on host.cshtml

Tags: authorization, blazor-server-side

I have my app locked down by allowing only authorised users at hosts.cshtml and using the AuthorizeView tag in app.razor. The net affect is to force all users to a login page if they are unauthorized.

This works perfectly well until someone on a higher paycheck then me decides that one or two pages should be anonymous. Setting the page to @attribute [AllowAnonymous] has no effect because the page is never reached.

Is there a strategy to implement this, hopefully in app.razor?

Here is my `hosts.cshtml`...

```
@page "/"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [Authorize]

@namespace U3A.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

And `app.razor` looks like this:

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeView>
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
                <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
            </AuthorizeView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. The ASP.NET 3.1 solution is here...

[Blazor Allow Anonymous For Razor Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434131/blazor-allow-anonymous-for-razor-page?rq=1)

For my Blazor 6 app I did the following...

1. Create a folder within the **Pages** folder titled **Public** and within it...
2. Created the file **_PublicHost.cshtml**
3. Created the file **_PublicLayout.cshtml**
4. Created the file **PublicApp.razor**
5. Created the file **PublicMainLayout.razor**
6. Created the file **_Imports.razor**
7. Created my public page **ClassScheduleView.razor**
8. Changed *MapFallbackToPage* in **Program.cs**

**_PublicHost.cshtml**

```
@page "/Public"

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization

@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

@namespace U3A.Pages.Public
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = "_PublicLayout";
}

<component type="typeof(PublicApp)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

**_PublicLayout.cshtml**

There is no special change to the standard **_Layout.cshtml** required here. I have read that `<base href="~/" />` should be changed to `<base href="~/public" />` but this caused null reference exceptions in 3rd party DevExpress components. I left it as is without any issue.

**_Imports.razor**

Nothing special here.

**PublicApp.razor**

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(PublicMainLayout)" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(PublicMainLayout)">
            <p class="alert alert-warning">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**PublicMainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>

@code {

}
```

**ClassScheduleView.razor**

This is just a standard Blazor page. The trick here is to ensure the correct @page directive...

```
@page "/Public/ClassScheduleView"
```

**Program.cs**

```
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/Public/{*path:nonfile}", "/Public/_PublicHost");
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Initially this solution worked for me. After a few months, I needed to create a page with more componets with logic, initially, I just had a static html page as public.

The page is displayed properly, but it gets an error when it tries to make an HTTP request to /authorize the endpoint and crashing the application because of CORS.

I don't expect to see any authorization initiation in this public page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhgzC.png

Comment: We're using .NET 6.0 and following these steps just results in a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when going to the public route. However, I can view the public page if I login.

Answer (score 0):

The way to achive this is by specifying the attribute within your razor components itself.

Adding this attribute on all pages that require authorization will work. Simply leave out the pages which should be available for everyone.

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```