# ASP.NET (Blazor): Trigger windows authentication popup only on a single page

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, windows-authentication

My Blazor webapp (ASP.NET) should consist of pages, that allow anonymous users (*url/noauth*) and a single page, which needs authentication (*url/auth*).
The authentication mechanism to be used is windows authentication (which includes an automatically triggered popup for logging in, if authentication fails).

**Popup:**
[image: authentication popup]

The desired behavior is to

1. show the noauth page to any user
2. show the auth page to authenticated users only (e.g. browser inside intranet)
3. show a popup asking for windows credentials to non-authenticated users requesting auth page

My code:

**Auth.razor**

```
@page "/auth"
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3>Auth</h3>
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <AuthorizeView>
        <Authorized>
            <p>You are authorized</p>
        </Authorized>
        <NotAuthorized>
            <p>You are not authorized</p>
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code {

}
```

**NoAuth.razor**

```
@page "/noAuth"
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<h3>NoAuth</h3>

@code {

}
```

**Program.cs (Version A)**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

This way the authentication check works fine, I am able to view the noauth page and the auth page shows me, that I am not authorized. However I do not have any means of authenticating/logging in (no popup is shown).

**Program.cs (Version B)**

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
```

This way, when calling the auth page without being logged in I get a popup asking for my windows credentials (desired), however I get the same popup on the noauth page (not desired).

How can I either exclude the noauth page from the popup-showing-mechanism , or trigger the popup for the auth page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned `Blazor webapp (` in your statement, so I deduce you are now using blazor in .net 8. If we are using .net 8 for authentication, we should use `builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();` instead of `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`. We could see the [migration guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#migrate-the-cascadingauthenticationstate-component-to-cascading-authentication-state-services) here.

Then the program.cs we have should like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    //options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
    //options.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("admin"));
});
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
```

You might notice that I comment line `//options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;` that's because the default policy would make us sign in first before we visit any view, no matter whether we added `[AllowAnonymous]` attribution.

Then we could add `@attribute [Authorize]` to components which requiring authentication, and `@attribute [AllowAnonymous]` or don't add attribtue to components which doesn't require authentcation.

For example, my counter.razor and my home.razor

```
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@attribute [Authorize]

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>


@page "/"
<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
```

[image]

Comment: if you are having a blazor server app in .net 7, you could create a sample via VS template which choosing windows auth as the authentication type, then I could reproduce your issue, that's because we require a 401 response to trigger the signin popup, while blazor server in .net 7 has all the page components rendered in the server side so that we couldn't have specific pages to be allow anonymous by attribute. The work around we might have is, using cshtml instead of razor components if they are allowed to be noauth to visit.

Comment: Or try [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71434131/blazor-allow-anonymous-for-razor-page) which having 2 _Host.cshtml.-

Comment: Thank you very much.
Using .net 8 makes it as simple as it should be!